# Static Public IP for Server on a Network that has a Dynamic Public IP

Tags: server, 18.04, ip

I want to know if there is a way to have get my server a static ip on my network so that people can connect to it using that ip without it changing and me having to get the new public ip. If there is a way to do this please respond.

Comment: Are the people who want to connect in your local network, or outside of your router and firewall? The answer depends... so please click [edit] and tell us where they are. Please don't use Add Comment as old comments can get pushed off screen when new comments are posted.

Comment: Consider using `Dynamic DNS`. Google it. Check out https://www.maketecheasier.com/best-dynamic-dns-providers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned it being a server and public IP, I'm going to assume you are talking about accessing it outside of your local network. In that case, to get a static IP you'd have to talk to your ISP about getting one. Or as heynnema mentioned, using a dynamic DNS service so you don't have to worry about remembering your IP in the first place.

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for.